# validator in angular reactive form not working properly?

Tags: angular, validation, asynchronous, angular-reactive-forms

I have this service, I am trying to validate the zip code field, but  (result ? null : { IsInvalid: true }) never executes.

Is reactive form working properly or is it faulty logic/usage?

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AddressService {
  public states = []
  public zipCodeValid = new Subject<boolean>();
  public zipCodeValid1 = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {
   this.states = ['AL', 'FL']
  }

  createValidator(fieldName: string): AsyncValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): Observable<ValidationErrors> => {
      return this.checkZipInAllStates(control.value)
        .pipe(
          map((result: boolean) =>
            result ? null : { IsInvalid: true }
          )
        );
    };
  }


  checkZipInAllStates(value: string) {
    if (this.states && value) {
      return of(this.states.some((state) => {
        return this.checkZipCodeBelongsStateObservable(state, value)
      }))
    }
    else {
      return of(false)
    }
  }



  checkZipCodeBelongsStateObservable(state: string, zipCode: string) {
    return this.httpService.httpGet(environment.coreApiEndpoint + `zipCodesMaster/zipCodeBelongsState/${zipCode}/${state}`)
      .pipe(map((response) => {
        return response.Data
      }))
  }

}
```

```
 CLIENT_GENERAL_FORM_VALIDATORS = this.formBuilder.group({
'zip': ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.pattern(/^\d{5}(-)?(\d{4})?$/), Validators.composeAsync([this.addressService.createValidator('zip')])])],
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should place the `asyncValidatorFn` in the third parameter according to [Angular FormControl constructor signature Overload #4]. Otherwise the `asynValidatorFn` will not working correctly.

```
CLIENT_GENERAL_FORM_VALIDATORS = this.formBuilder.group({
  zip: [
    '',
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^\d{5}(-)?(\d{4})?$/),
    ]),
    [this.addressService.createValidator('zip')],
  ],
});
```

2. (Optional) The `Validators.compose()` which will perform all the validations provided can be omitted and replaced with:

```
CLIENT_GENERAL_FORM_VALIDATORS = this.formBuilder.group({
  zip: [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern(/^\d{5}(-)?(\d{4})?$/),
    ],
    [this.addressService.createValidator('zip')],
  ],
});
```

3. Another concern is that in the `checkZipInAllStates` method, the `Observable` returned from the `if` condition will always return `true`. For your scenario, you are trying to submit multiple requests by iterating the `states` array. You should work with [`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) operator to fire and wait for all the observables to be completed, and next use [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap) to emit a new Observable with any of the previous observables was `true`.

```
checkZipInAllStates(value: string): Observable<boolean> {
  if (this.states && value) {

    let observables$: Observable<boolean>[] = this.states.map((state) =>
      this.checkZipCodeBelongsStateObservable(state, value)
    );

    return forkJoin(observables$).pipe(
      switchMap((values: boolean[]) => of(values.some((x) => x)))
    );
  } else {
    return of(false);
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jijpyp?file=src%2Faddress.service.ts)